# how to disable a part of my script on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that has two "views", a gallery view and a list view. When in gallery view, I need to watch the window width and resize the thumbnails tray on the fly. However, when in list view (I load it via ajax using jquery `.load()`) I don't need that bit of code anymore because the thumbnails tray doesn't exist anymore. The page still renders fine but my browser throws errors behind the scene. I've tried placing the "window width" code in an if-statement, but it seems to me the script checks only on page load and never checks again if the thumbs element exists so it just never deactivates. Any thoughts? [Here is my website if it helps](http://distantfuturejosh.com/landjacks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove event handlers with `off`, then replace them with `on`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for seeing through my poorly worded question. So to be clear for anyone else who sees this post, in its most basic form I check the window like this `$(window).on("load resize", function() { //do stuff here });` then when I switch views and don't need it anymore I turn it off like this `$(window).off();`

Comment: @wetjosh or you can remove only specific handlers, or all those for an event, e.g., $(window).off('resize') or $(window).off('resize', someFunc)